# Chebyshev Rational Approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Find the Chebyshev rational approximation of degree 4 with m=n=2 for $f(x)=\sin(x)$
.

Now I do have a program that can evaluate this But its asking me to find the coefficients of the Chebyshev polynomial. So since its degree 5 then I must have 8 coefficients for some odd reason. How would I find the coefficients in the most efficient manner